# Vertical Alignment (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone please help me vertically middle align the first two columns of my table. Please see the code below:

```
&nbsp;
<table border="1" style="width: 625px;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" rowspan="1"><b>Property 1</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">Yellow</td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">Ad</td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">abcdefgfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
        <ul>
            <li>12345</li>
            <li>4556</li>
            <li>793</li>
        </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

It appear like this currently:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgEsQ.png)

Comment: they are aligned middle by default - perhaps your CSS (which you haven't shown) is causing it to appear otherwise - see https://jsfiddle.net/6orzxf9L/ - that's all the code you showed, and all the cells are vertical aligned middle

Comment: A snapshot of how it appears and how you want it may help

Comment: [Never asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D%22vertical+align%22) ..?

Comment: I have added a picture of how it currently appears on the post as a link

Comment: I am using salesforce, Jaromanda.  Is there anything I could do to align it on that platform?

Answer (score 2):

To make sure that your table is vertically aligned, add a class to your table and add this css on the head part

```
.verticalTable tr td {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Here's [a link](http://jsbin.com/wakabov/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: its not working for me. Can you tell me how to add a div.container?

Comment: &nbsp;
<table border="1" style="width: 625px;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" rowspan="1"><b>Property 1</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">Yellow</td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">Ad</td>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">abcdefgfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
        <ul>
            <li>12345</li>
            <li>4556</li>
            <li>793</li>
        </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

Comment: 'div' defines a division or a section in an HTML document; it is also used to group block-elements to format them with css. check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp) for documentation. I've updated my code, please check  [this](http://jsbin.com/wakabov/edit?html,output) out so you can have a visual

Answer (score 1):

try adding this css:

```
table tr td:nth-child(1),td:nth-child(2){
    text-align: center;
}
```